# Issue with xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to copy a back up file from a remote system to local using

> EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell 'XCopy src dest'

command. 
The above mentioned command returns file not found error. However the `XCopy` command copies file from the `remote system` to the `local system` when run in command prompt of the `local system`. Can somebody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a remote server. When you attempt this from the command line you are using your permissions.

However, xp_cmdshell is run with the permissions of the SQL Server service account. Of course this account should be run with minimum permissions, you may need to increase its permissions to the other server.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Also, don't forget that when the xp_cmdshell executes under the SQL account permissions that mapped network drive letters won't be available.  You must use UNC path.  i.e. \\servername\sharename\path\file